# How could I change values in database sqlite time to time automatically in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime, reset

I need to do a function or class in Android which I can reset certain values ​​of a table SQLITE on certain dates. 
For example, **Monday at 0:00 o´clock set zero value, the 1st of each month set zero another value and January 1 of each year puts other value to zero** . 
How could I do that automatically without the user of the app you have to touch anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alarm:

```
    @Override 
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
       super.onCreate(icicle);
       Intent intent = new Intent("com.mycompany.myapp");
       intent.putExtra("DoTheWork", true);
       DateTime today = new DateTime().withTimeAtStartOfDay();
       DateTime tomorrow = today.plusDays(1).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
       pendingintentResetAlarms = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(con, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
       alarmManager.cancel(pendingintentResetAlarms);
       alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, tomorrow.getMillis(), 86400000, pendingintentResetAlarms);
       AlarmReceiver receiver = new AlarmReceiver();
       this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(com.mycompany.myapp));.
    }
```

have a receiver:

```
    private class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            boolean bRestAlarms = bundle.getBoolean("DoTheWork", false);
            if (bRestAlarms) {
                //call your subbroutine here
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Don't forget to unregister the receiver in your onDestroy.

**EDIT** 
Find every Monday using Calendar object:

```
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(); 
while( date.get( Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK ) != Calendar.MONDAY )
     date.add( Calendar.DATE, 1 );
}
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingintentResetAlarms);
```

You can get the same idea about first of month, first of year.

Comment: thanks but How I could configure the alarm for every monday, every 1st of the each month and every 1st of year?? and the class DateTime, where is??

Comment: @elvega updated answer.  I answered your first question, but you'll have to do a little googling or figuring out the logic of the other two.

Comment: the pendingintentResetAlarms  and con  what type are?

Comment: the pendingintentResetAlarms, con and   alarmManager what type are?  aren't declared